# Spring mail error while connecting to outlook.com smtp server

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email through my outlook.com account (mapped to a specific domain, my email id would be like emailId@mydomain.com

I am getting the following exception.

> 2014-03-14 00:27:55,314 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable -
>   Invocation of method 'sendMail' on target class [class
>   com.sixthsense.lws.scheduler.TestMailSenderJob] failed
>   org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Email
>   address ;   nested exception is:
>     com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Email
>   address ; message exception details (1) are: Failed message 1:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Email
>   address ;   nested exception is:
>     com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Email
>   address
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
>     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
>     at
>   com.sixthsense.lws.scheduler.TestMailSenderJob.sendMail(TestMailSenderJob.java:34)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Email
>   address
>
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1616)
>     ... 20 more

My spring configuration are as below

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp-mail.outlook.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
         <property name="username" value="userid@mydomian.com" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Following code sends the email

```
@Service
public class TestMailSenderJob {

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
        return mailSender;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    public void sendMail()
    {
        System.out.println("############invoked sendMail");
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

        message.setTo("to@mailId.com");
        message.setSubject("Test mail "+new Date().toString());
        message.setText("test body");
        getMailSender().send(message);
        System.out.println("######### email send");
    }

}
```

I am using oracle supplied jars for email version javamail-1.4.7 .
Edit: I am able to send receive emails in my outlook account(used for smtp in the program) through outlook web interface.

Comment: Well, the server responded with `5.5.4 Invalid Email address` which means that it doesn't accept `to@mailId.com`. Did you try any valid address? Is the `mail from` [address](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html#setFrom%28java.lang.String%29) correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed atlast, added from in message

```
 message.setFrom("from@mailId.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I read in many places in the stacktrace this: "Invalid Email address". Please, check it in your code.

Another thing, for safety sake, please use the javax.mail-1.4.7 from maven repo.

Comment: Or better yet, the current version - JavaMail 1.5.1.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, you've true :) I hope that this version will appear in Maven Repo asap, too.

Comment: It's already in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.1/javax.mail-1.5.1.jar) as well as the [java.net maven repository](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.1/javax.mail-1.5.1.jar).  The maven coordinates are on the [JavaMail java.net project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.1_Release).